# How to lock unity's "Show Desktop" button

Tags: unity

I have added a show desktop button to unity but it keeps moving down towards the bottom of the launcher. I want to pin and lock it in place, so that it is always under the ubuntu logo.

How can I do that?

Comment: Drag and drop it where you wish. It will remain where you will put it.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu You can't drag the 'show desktop', 'show workspace' and 'Trash' icons. They will always be at the bottom. Also the 'Dash Home' icon, it will always be at the top. Unless you recompile the source code. Tested in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @Parto That is not for the show desktop icon :)

Comment: @Parto I can drag/drop "show desktop" and "show workspaces" ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind and JacobVlijm Which Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: 14.04  but I also used to move them to the top on 13.10 and 13.04 to name 2 ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why drag and drop does not work as a permanent solution in your case, it seems for some reason the changed order does not stick via GUI.

However, you can bypass the GUI and set the Unity Launcher items order by command line directly, which should do the job if the GUI way fails.

**Getting the current launcher items list**

Run in a terminal:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```

The output will be a list of your current launcher items, looking like:

```
['item1', 'item2', 'unity://desktop-icon']
```

Copy the list and safe it in a textfile as a backup in case anything might go wrong.

**Place the show desktop icon in another position**

Your `show desktop` mention is called:

```
'unity://desktop-icon'
```

Move it to the position you'd like to have it it in the list, and apply the new list. The changed list should look like:

```
['unity://desktop-icon', 'item1', 'item2']
```

**Apply the new order**

Apply the new order by the command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['unity://desktop-icon''item2', 'item3']"
```

(mind the quotes around the list!)

Comment: Thanks, I can drag and reposition the icon, but after a reboot or logging out, it goes to the bottom of the luncher.

Comment: @mFat but does the above procedure not work???? That is hardly possible.